# Bind attr values DropDown by JQuery?

Tags: jquery, attr, html-select

Iam trying to bind attr values to dropdown as i need more than 2 values to get bind to dropdown.

```
    success: function (JSONData) {
            var Ports = $.parseJSON(JSONData.d);
            $(".ddlFrom").empty();                
            $(".ddlFrom").append("<option  value=''>   </option>");

            $.each(Ports, function (index, value) {
            $(".ddlFrom").append("<option value='" + value.ID + "'>" + value.Name + "</option>")
                                .attr("Sequence", value.Sequence);

            });
```

But here iam having list of Data coming to Dropdown and iam getting last sequence when i select any item in the dropdown., i want respective sequnce of selected value of dropdown

Any help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this :

```
var Ports = $.parseJSON(JSONData.d);
var select = $(".ddlFrom");
select.empty();
$.each(Ports, function (index, value) {
    select.append("<option value='" + value.ID + "'>" + value.Name + "</option>")
    select.find(":last").attr("Sequence", value.Sequence);
});
```

Or (a simpler way) would be to add this with the HTML you're appending like this :

```
var Ports = $.parseJSON(JSONData.d);
var select = $(".ddlFrom");
select.empty();
$.each(Ports, function (index, value) {
        select.append("<option value='" + value.ID + "' Sequence='" + value.Sequence + "'>" + value.Name + "</option>")
    });
```

On a higher stance, it isnt HTML semantics to use custom attributes (nothing wrong, but might make ur HTML look ugly). You could maybe try using `data` which [jquery](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.data/) recommends for storing info abt the element.

To get a value out of this, be sure to navigate into the select element using jquery's `find()` like this:

```
$(this).find(":selected").attr("Sequence")
```

Else you'll end up with an `undefined` error :)

[Working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ENCVc/2/) (Updated)

Comment: i dont want only last value, i want associated sequence value of that selected dropdown

Comment: let me see if ive got this right - first option -> first sequence, second option- second sequence, so on, right?

Comment: Yes..., If i have 3 records say id 1,2,3 and name a,b,c seq 01,02,03 and if i select a from dropdown i must get seq as 01..,

Comment: In your second ans i must use Sequnce as attribute to use it correct?

Comment: Do you want the value which i comes out to be the corresponding sequence? If thats the thing then this must suffice. Check that fiddle i added for more clarity

Comment: But thats what you were trying to do werent you? Trying to add the sequence as an attribute to the corresponding option?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/30806/discussion-between-passionatecoder-and-pink)